# Spring Web Flow with Struts 1.x - is it possible?

Tags: struts, spring-webflow

Is it possible to combine these platforms? I can't find any examples of this and the documentation only mentions integration with Spring WebMVC or JSF. We're currently on a Struts 1.x app using Spring 4.1.4. Can Web Flow sit on top of this stack without major effort? Am I right in thinking that Web Flow would effectively need to replace the struts actions in the parts of the application where we wanted to use it?

Comment: Nope. Struts 1.x is pureless stateless Web framework with page, request and session scope while Spring Web Flow contains scope management. E.g., you can **never** do `@ConversationScoped` on Struts 1.x. Also, Struts 1.x doesn't support annotations. Finally, Struts 1.x has been abandoned a long time back. Rather use Struts 2.x instead.